# Angular2 canAcrivate based on route parameter?

Tags: angular, routes

I need to implement a route guard for my angular2 app based on the URL parameter that passed in the routing, for example:

```
http://myapp.com/test1/sites -------> where my routes use the test1 as a parameter :sitename
```

so if the passed parameter == test1 then canActivate return true, otherwise return false.

so how to implement this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route declaration:

```ts
{
  path: ':sitename/sites',
  component: SomeComponent,
  canActivate: [CanActivateSite]
}
```

Then the guard implementation:

```ts
@Injectable()
class CanActivateSite implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return route.params.sitename == 'test1';
  }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to implement the same on double parameters? like :sitename/:class ? and how to get the second parameter ? the class

Answer (score 0):

A route guard class can implement the CanActivate interface which forces you to define a canActivate function. This function takes in 2 parameters: ActivatedRouteSnapshot and RouterStateSnapshot.  Take a look at ActivatedRouteSnapshot...it contains data about the route including an object of params.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRouteSnapshot-interface.html